# Magento2 custom module redirection on catalogsearch page issue

Tags: magento2.2.3

I have created one custom module Coupon_DiscountCoupon in Magento 2.2.3 but after accessing it from URL it is redirecting me on catalog search module https://alice-dorsia.betaroiup.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=Coupon_DiscountCoupon 
Can anyone help me in finding valid URL for accessing that custom module in Magento 2.2.3?

Comment: Have u created a routes for the module

Comment: Yes below is the routes.xml  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="discountcoupon" frontName="discountcoupon">
            <module name="Coupon_DiscountCoupon" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>   I am accessing module with URL https://alice-dorsia.betaroiup.com/discountcoupon and https://alice-dorsia.betaroiup.com/index.php/discountcoupon